# How to import a text file to sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, import

I have the following text-file with 48.891 names. I would like to import them to a mySQL database. I need the first 3 characters with the gender and the name. The rest should be ignored.

```
M  Aad                                  4                                             $
M  Aadam                                          1                                   $
F  Aadje                                1                                             $
M  Ådne                      +                 1                                      $
M  Aadu                                           12                                  $
?F Aaf                                  1                                             $
F  Aafke                                4                                             $
?  Aafke                                 1                                            $
F  Aafkea                                1                                            $
M  Aafko                                1                                             $
M  Aage                                       761                                     $
M  Åge                       +                56                                      $
F  Aagje                              1 2                                             $
F  Aagot                                       1                                      $
F  Ågot                      +                 2                                      $
F  Aagoth                                      1                                      $
F  Ågoth                     +                 1                                      $
M  Åke                       +                118                                     $
M  Aalbert                              1                                             $
M  Aalderich                             1                                            $
M  Aalderk                               1                                            $
```

The database handling isn't my question. The problem is how to filter only the gender and name in the textfile.
Thnaks for any help in advance.

Comment: you can try wtih SQL XML for this..

Comment: How does the db-structure look like? Is it just one table?

Comment: I would say using regex

Comment: its just on table with gender and name

Comment: Since you've tagged [tag:PHP], text operation in PHP in your case seems quite simple. Just open the file, read line-by-line, process, and insert into database.

Answer (score 0):

To do this only in SQL , you can see `LOAD DATA INFILE` or you can do it with a little program.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the [ETL software Kettle by Pentaho](http://kettle.pentaho.com/) makes it pretty easy to import text files into mysql (especially if you don't have the most technical background.  The documentation is kind of sparse, and this software is far from perfect, but I've found that I can often import data in a fraction of the time I would have to spend writing a script for one specific file.  You can select a text file input and specify the delimiters, fixed width, etc.. and then simply export directly into your SQL server (they support MySql, SQLite, Oracle, and much more).  The drag and drop interface is great for anyone who doesn't want to write code every time they run an import.